# How to initialize a mono repo and create-react-app inside monorepo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, monorepo

I want to initialize a monorepo, and then initialize apps inside the `packages` folder. I found a bunch of examples of how to do this. But, what I want to achieve is, I want to keep all the `node_modules` at the root level.

```
--monorepo
 |--node_modules
 |--packages
 | |--create-react-app-1
 | | |--src
 | | |--{...rest}
 | |--create-react-app-2
 | | |--src
 | | |--{...rest}
 |--package.json
```

So, all the `node_modules` are at the root level and all the packages are using them from the root level. All the `dependencies` and `dev-dependencies` are listed in the root level `package.json`.

I want to use `yarn` as the package manager as well.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: I would recommend you to use Turborepo, a very useful and easy-to-use tool to achieve what you want

Comment: @NirBerko Thanks for your suggestion. I went with `@nrwl/nx` which seems to be the parent of Turborepo.